# Parsing JSON data in Angular that was returned from a Spring controller

Tags: json, angular, rest, ngfor

I have a strange problem with trying to JSON data returned from a Spring API to populate a list in Angular. I have a datasets-list.component.ts with the following code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datasets-list',
  templateUrl: './datasets-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datasets-list.component.css']
})

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DatasetsListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  API_SERVER:string=""; //url of API Gateway

  DatasetsMetadata:any; // Object

  ngOnInit(): void {

    // Get the metadata from the API Gateway
    let API_SERVER = "http://localhost:8443/datasets";
       
    let resp = this.http.request("GET", API_SERVER,{responseType:"text"});
    resp.subscribe((data)=>this.DatasetsMetadata=data);
    }
}
```

I then have the HTML in datasets-list.component.html to show the raw data as well as try to list the name property two different ways, as follows:

```
<form class="OodlerDatasetsForm">
    <h2 id="DatasetsLabel">Datasets</h2>
    <p>{{DatasetsMetadata}}</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in DatasetsMetadata">
            {{x.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let element of DatasetsMetadata">{{element.name}},{{element.code}},{{element.frequency}}</li>
    </ul>
  </form>
```

When I load the page in the browser, the

{{DatasetsMetadata}}

element shows the data as follows:

```
[{"name":"S&P 500 Stock Market Index","code":"SP500","frequency":"Daily"},{"name":"Dow Jones Industrial Average Daily Closing Price","code":"DJIA","frequency":"Daily"},{"name":"U.S. Industrial Production Index","code":"INDPRO","frequency":"Monthly"},{"name":"Gold Prices Daily Spot Value","code":"GSPD","frequency":"Daily"},{"name":"Silver Prices Daily Spot Value","code":"SSPD","frequency":"Daily"},{"name":"Copper Prices Spot Value","code":"CSPD","frequency":"Daily"},{"name":"All-Transactions House Price Index for the United States","code":"USSTHPI","frequency":"Quarterly"},{"name":"U.S. National Unemployment Rate","code":"USNURM","frequency":"Monthly"},{"name":"Crude Oil Prices: West Texas Intermediate","code":"DCOILWTICO","frequency":"Daily"}]
```

I already tried JSON.parse() and that didn't work. I appreciate any assistance you can give.

Comment: I'd suggest creating model classes to capture the response explicitly instead of using 'any' - this might give you some additional pointers.

Comment: Working on that approach. Thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: Hi Tim, have you found a solution? I can try to reproduce the issue for you if you want but only if you still need a solution. Feel free to get back.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced your issue and found a solution which helps in the development of your feature. Now you can isolate your issue without questioning if retrieving the data from the API functions properly.

I have added the following class to a folder on the same height as "app"
src/models/datasetsmetadata.ts

```
export class DatasetsMetadata {
  public name: string;
  public code: string;
  public frequency: string;
}
```

Besides that I added a file to the assets folder named 'datasetsreponse.json' with the exact JSON list of stock exchanges your mentioned.

I modified the tsconfig.json file in the root of the Angular project to include the following flags in 'compilerOptions':

"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,

These settings are needed to load Javascript Objects from files.
NOTE: make sure to restart the compilation process after your modified tsconfig.json.

The HTML file for datasets-list.component.html is now:

```
<form>
  <h2 id="DatasetsLabel">Datasets</h2>
  <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let element of DatasetsMetadata">{{element.name}}, {{element.code}}, {{element.frequency}}</li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

The TS file now is as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DatasetsMetadata } from 'src/models/datasetsmetadata';
import DatasetsMetadataListJSON from '../../assets/datasetsresponse.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-datasets-list',
  templateUrl: './datasets-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datasets-list.component.sass']
})
export class DatasetsListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  API_SERVER = '';

  // DatasetsMetadata: any; // old

  DatasetsMetadata: DatasetsMetadata[];

  ngOnInit(): void {

    // Get the metadata from the API Gateway
    // let API_SERVER = "http://localhost:8443/datasets";

    // let resp = this.http.request("GET", API_SERVER, { responseType: "text" });
    // resp.subscribe((data) => this.DatasetsMetadata = data);

    this.DatasetsMetadata = DatasetsMetadataListJSON;
    console.log(this.DatasetsMetadata);
  }
}
```

The result in my Chrome browser:
[image: Result]

Comment: I followed your suggestion to switch to a model class. That eventually worked for me.

Comment: Glad to hear! Good luck with your project.